# Navigation From Right To Left In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

As written in the title i am trying to find a way to change the navigation style from left-to-right to a right-to-left Arabic style.
This is a simple NavigationView code I made:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                    Text("Go To Destination")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Text")
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be automatically done in system with RTL locales, or forced with `flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)`, and I recall that worked, but ... seems they broken something... again.

Comment: Did you try to set your iPhone in a language with right to left reading ?

Comment: You can also just add Arabic in favorite language and set this language for your app only so you won’t get lost in settings .

Comment: @PtitXav but i am trying to do it for every person that downloads the app not only one phone